# Calculating between dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

This is what I have so far using jquery. I do not know why my checkRecord button will not display the number of days between the two dates. I am obviously missing something.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
'use strict';      
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
var dayNames= ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"]

var newDate = new Date();
 newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()); 

$('#safetyRecord').hide();

$('#today').html(dayNames[newDate.getDay()] + "," +' ' + monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getDate() + ","+ ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());

$('#checkRecord').click(function(){
var $daysSinceLastAccident = $('#daysSinceLastAccident');

var dateOfLastAccident = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val());

var today = new Date();

$daysSinceLastAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - dateOfLastAccident.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

$daysSinceLastAccident.text(daysSinceLastAccident);
$('#safetyRecord').show();
});

});
```

Comment: If you've already fixed some of your typos, don't forget to edit your post so people can see.

Comment: Did you already `console.log` your values or use a debugger to make sure everything is what you expect them to be? Is the date value being parsed correctly? If yes, jsfiddle this.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

`var today = new date;` and `$('#safetyRecord').show;`

to

`var today = new Date();` and `$('#safetyRecord').show();`

Comment: @user2856563 It would be easier to help you if you can provide a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
>  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate());
```

does nothing, it just sets the date of *newDate* to its current value.

```
> var $daysSinceLastAccident = $('#daysSinceLastAccident');
> [...] 
> $daysSinceLastAccident = Math.floor((today.getTime() - ...
```

Initially *$daysSinceLastAccident* is assigned a reference to a  jQuery object, then a number. What is the purpose of the initial assignment?

```
> $daysSinceLastAccident.text(daysSinceLastAccident);
```

But you seem to expect it to still be a jQuery object.

Also:

```
> var today = new Date();
```

There is already a *newDate* variable that likely has exactly the same value, maybe 1ms earlier, that has been used to display the current date. There doesn't seem to be any reason not to use it again.

Note that if you want the difference between two date objects in days, you can set the time to noon on the relevant dates, subtract and divide by ms/day, then round.

E.g for the above:

```
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setHours(12,0,0,0); // 12:00:00.000

// You should never leave parsing of date strings to the Date object
// I'll assume here that it "works" in the limited cases you've tested
var dateOfLastAccident = new Date($('#dateOfLastAccident').val());
dateOfLastAccident.setHours(12,0,0,0);

var daysSinceLastAccident = Math.round((newDate - dateOfLastAccident) / 8.64e7);
```

You should manually parse date strings, it's not hard. E.g. given input like 2013-10-09 you can do:

```
function parseISODateString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/g);
  var d = new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2]);

  // Return d if s was a valid date string, NaN otherwise.
  return (d && d.getFullYear() == s[0] && d.getDate() == s[2])? d : NaN;
}
```

You should test the input string and returned value to make it robust.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest function to get the difference dates duration in years,months and days...
check this code

```
function getDatesDiff(from,to){
    from = new Date(from);
    to = new Date(to);

     if (isNaN(to - from)) return "";

    from.setDate(from.getDate()-1);
    var fullMonths=0;
    var days=0;
    var fromDate=new Date(from);
    var finalDate=new Date(fromDate);
    var nextMonth=new Date(new Date(fromDate).setMonth(new Date(fromDate).getMonth() + 1));
    var result='';

    while(from<=to){
         if(+from == +nextMonth){
               fullMonths++;
               finalDate=new Date(nextMonth);
               nextMonth.setMonth(nextMonth.getMonth() + 1);
        }
              from.setDate(from.getDate() + 1);

    }


     days=Math.round((to-finalDate)/(1000*60*60*24));

      if(Math.round(fullMonths/12)>0)
        result=Math.round(fullMonths/12) + "year"+(Math.round(fullMonths/12)>1?'s':'');

      if(parseInt(fullMonths%12)>0)
        result+=" "+fullMonths%12 + "month"+(parseInt(fullMonths%12)>1?'s':'')  ;

        if(days>0)
            result+=" "+ days + "day"+(days>1?'s':'');

    return result;
}
```

this is jsfiddle.......

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1rxnmvnd/
```